# Drag & Drop issues AUI

Tags: drag-and-drop, liferay-aui

I have been trying to use Drag and Drop functionality between two lists. I got an example from the link : http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/scroll-list.html

I have checked that all methods specified in YUI (in the link) is present for AUI too. The problem is that the drag event works perfectly but drop event does not work. The drag:drophit event does not get activated.

I am using Liferay 6.1.2 Ga3. Did anybody face this issue before? If yes, can you please provide me some clues on it?

Thank you,